# How do I configure a parameterized git alias?

Tags: git

I frequently run

```
git log -10 --author="<author name>" --grep="<story of interest>"
```

Is it possible to configure a git alias similar to

```
git by "<author name>" "<story of interest>" -10
```

that will accomplish the same thing?

[The documentation](https://githowto.com/aliases) makes no mention of parameters.

Comment: You could do a quick bash script that did it.

Comment: This subverts the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create alias as a shell command:

```
git config alias.agrep '!f() { git log -10 --author="$1" --grep="$2"; }; f'
```

Now call `git agrep` with 2 parameters: `git agrep Matt test`.

See [GitAlias repo](https://github.com/GitAlias/gitalias) for dozens of useful aliases and examples. Full disclosure: I'm a contributor.