# What is the equivalent git ls-files command to see the same information as git status?

Tags: git, merge, git-ls-files

When I merge code and there are conflicts, I have a quick command that lists all the files in the "modified" block of git status. It's a hack using **grep** and **git status**.

```
function gitfix() {
   echo 'git status | grep modified:' 
}
```

It's nice because I just do

```
emacs -nw $(gitfix)
```

and my editor loads up all the files that need conflicts resolved.

But I want a more proper version that uses **git ls-files**.

The **git ls-files** command has statuses like "modified" and "unmerged" and I'm not sure what those mean as regards merge conflicts.

Yeah, I know I'm lazy (I'm a programmer) for not figuring this out myself but intentionally creating conflicts is a pain in the ass if I'm the only committer. Anyone using **git ls-files** to list the files that have conflicts during a merge?

Comment: To resolve conflicts I use alias [`edit-unmerged`](https://github.com/GitAlias/gitalias/blob/e5d366c356a15ad91bd84344af12b15fbccf9bb9/gitalias.txt#L1215) and then [`add-unmerged`](https://github.com/GitAlias/gitalias/blob/e5d366c356a15ad91bd84344af12b15fbccf9bb9/gitalias.txt#L1205). So I primarily use `ls-files --unmerged`. Full disclosure: I am a [contributor](https://github.com/GitAlias/gitalias/commits?author=phdru) to the repo.

Comment: @phd ooo, I didn't even know about this repo, cool-o-rama!

Comment: @matt I mentioned the repo in comments many times. :-) Once even in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44548013/7976758). :-)))

Answer (score 1):

[phd's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70561468/what-is-the-equivalent-git-ls-files-command-to-see-the-same-information-as-git-s#comment124741079_70561468) referring to [this line](https://github.com/GitAlias/gitalias/blob/e5d366c356a15ad91bd84344af12b15fbccf9bb9/gitalias.txt#L1215):

```
edit-unmerged = !"f() { git ls-files --unmerged | cut -f2 | sort -u ; }; `git var GIT_EDITOR` `f`"
```

is a direct answer to what you want to do, but it's worth pointing out that `git status` does a lot more than `git ls-files` *can* do.  Git is built around a "tool philosophy" and some tools are lower level and others are higher level; `git status` is relatively high level and incorporates things that have to be done via multiple invocations of multiple lower-level tools:

- It will count how many commits the current branch is ahead and/or behind its upstream, if there is a current branch and it has an upstream.  This requires using `git symbolic-ref` or similar to find the current branch, `git rev-parse` or similar to find its upstream, and `git rev-list --count --left-right` to do the counting.
- It will check to see if some files are unmerged, and if so, change its strategy.  The `git ls-files` command can do this but does not change strategy as a result: it takes one invocation of `git ls-files` to discover this, and then one or more separate invocations later depending on the strategy.
- It will compare `HEAD` (the current commit) vs the index: `git ls-files` can do this, but it takes multiple invocations of `git ls-files`.
- It will compare the index vs the staging area: `git ls-files` can do this too, but again it takes multiple invocations.

The main thing to know here is that `git ls-files` is oriented towards examining Git's index.  The index itself is a complicated beastie, but its main contents are a list of <file name, staging number, hash ID, cache data> tuples:

- the file name is the name of the file as it will appear in the next commit, if you make one now;
- the staging number is a numeric value between 0 and 3 inclusive;
- the hash ID is the internal blob hash for the file, or all-zero for an intent-to-add entry;
- the cache data include `lstat` data and flags like assume-unchanged and skip-worktree: stuff intended to make Git go fast and/or be more useful.

If all of these entries have staging number zero, there are no unmerged files.  Any entry with a nonzero staging number represents an unmerged file, and the staging number tells us its source:

- 1 = the file as it appears in the merge base;
- 2 = the file as it appears in `--ours`, i.e., the `HEAD` commit;
- 3 = the file as it appears in `--theirs`, i.e., the other commit.

The *name* of the file in each of these up-to-three nonzero stage entries is normally the same for all three, but when a file was renamed, Git's index entries get a little squirrelly here.  (There might, in theory, be more than three *entries*, though with just three stage numbers: Junio Hamano has mentioned on the mailing list that the intent was to allow multiple stage-1 entries during complex multiple-merge-base and/or octopus merges, for instance.  In practice that doesn't happen, though.  I think there are some additional issues here with the current index format that require either extensions or a new index format.  But they're all extremely rare in practice anyway.)  In any case, the presence of *any* nonzero stage numbers means that the index cannot be written out to a tree: `git write-tree` will fail.  Some Git scripts use this as a short-cut test for "do unmerged index entries exist":

```sh
unmerged=false
t=$(git write-tree 2>/dev/null) || unmerged=true
if $unmerged; then ...; fi # test for unmerged entries
```

though technically `git write-tree` could fail for other reasons (`.git/index` being unwritable due to full file system, over-quota status, and/or permissions issues for instance).

In any case, if *all* index entries are at stage zero, there are no unmerged files, and the index can be turned into a new commit.  The file contents in this proposed commit may match those in the `HEAD` commit, or not; they may match those in the working tree, or not; the index's set of files is independent of both of those.