# git: how to list only the paths of files needing merge?

Tags: git

After some operation that produces merge conflicts, we can do this:

```
$ git checkout
foo/bar/x.c: needs merge
foo/bar/y.c: needs merge
xyzzy/w.c: needs merge
```

Using nothing but some `git` command, how can we just get this output:

```
foo/bar/x.c
foo/bar/y.c
xyzzy/w.c
```

`git status` shows the files as `both modified:`, and using the `git status -s` format they show up in the output as:

```
UU foo/bar/x.c
UU foo/bar/y.c
UU xyzzy/w.c
```

so that doesn't meet the requirements. `git checkout` doesn't take anything resembling `--name-only`. `git diff --name-only` lists nothing but the files, but also includes files that do not have conflicts.

I want to avoid the anti-pattern of textually processing the output of git "porcelain" commands, which I obviously know how to do:

```
git status -s | awk '$1=="UU"&&$0=$2'
```

Therefore, I will spitefully retaliate against all answers in this vein by flagging and whatnot. Don't say you weren't warned.

Answer (score 4):

`git ls-files --unmerged` (or `git ls-files -u`) will do this. From the [git-book docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files):

> `-u`
>
> `--unmerged`
>
> Show unmerged files in the output (forces --stage)

Depending on your specific needs, you may want to include other statuses as well, or may want to include other "staging numbers" as described in this related StackOverflow question [What is the equivalent git ls-files command to see the same information as git status?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70569218/1426891).

As on the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/git), `git ls-files` is a *plumbing* command, so it should be stable and should not require additional processing.

Comment: `git ls-files -u` shows several columns of output, same in format as when `git ls-files --stage` is given. I can't find any way to just list the names, like what `git ls-files` does without any options.

Comment: The `ls-files -u` output has another problem: it lists three objects for each conflicted path. So if you just want the names, you have to de-duplicate triplicates.

Comment: @Kaz Yes, that's the "(forces --stage)" described in the quoted documentation. I might have been overzealous in saying that it required no additional processing, but piping to `cut -d" " -f4 | sort -u` is still safe since the output is plumbing-stable. Alternatively, if you wanted to extract the hash numbers or file mode of a particular entry, you would need to filter based on that stage rather than disregarding it.